# Any way to input a command and execute it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = input('Enter something:') #e.g. input is print('Hello World')
# some function
print(a) #and then we get only `Hello World` out as we use print
```

I already researched executing shell commands via python but nothing related what I want to do. Do I need to change to language that's not python? Is it even possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For statements, use `exec(string)` (Python 2/3) or `exec string` (Python 2):

So rather than printing `a` it, use `exec`

Just as an aside, I would say this is ***highly insecure*** if you plan to use it in any software as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec`:

```py
>>> a = input("Enter something: ")
Enter something: print("hello world")
>>> exec(a)
hello world
```